# Run a C# script on Android Studio Project

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, face-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I am developing an app that uses Microsoft Cognitive services's Face API for facial recogonition. The App has been developed in Android Studio, but the training is done initially by a C# script created in visual studio.

Now I would like to add dynamic training to the app itself, ie if any face is detected by the camera, we can tag and add it to your trained dataset.

Can anyone give us the idea on how to do that or how to run that script from android studio itself on click of a button?

Comment: face-recognition is a wrong tag : your problem is not with how to do / implement face-recognition , it's basically with the mix of technologies you are working with, I would like to advice you to use Xamarin since your library is written using c#

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have to **rewrite your code in java** or make a **webservice** that you will invoke by sending a serialized image.

***Explanation :*** Basically the idea is to write a webservice using asp.net(since your script run on c# ), this webserice take as a parameter a string base 64 image and return a string base 64 treated image  .

This solution is a workaround , it will depend so much on the network.

The real solution would be to choose the correct tools (honestly i didn't understand the mix of technologies that you are using, for which goal and perspective).

Just keep in mind that : to connect two incompatibles systems(your case) we use a webservice.